# Output when running curl from groovy is send to error instead of stdout (Process)?

Tags: curl, groovy

For some reason running curl from groovy sends a successful call to error:

```
def command = ["curl", "-LO", "https://curl.se/download/curl-7.79.1.tar.gz"]
def process = command.execute()
StringWriter output = new StringWriter()
StringWriter error = new StringWriter()
process.waitForProcessOutput(output, error)
if(process.exitValue()) {
  throw new Exception("$error")
}

println "EXIT CODE: ${process.exitValue()}"
println "OUT: $output"
println "-------------------------------------------"
println "ERROR: $error"
println output.toString()
```

Running the above gives:

```
EXIT CODE: 0
OUT: 
-------------------------------------------
ERROR:   % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed

  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
100 4047k  100 4047k    0     0  7266k      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 7266k
```

why does groovy send that output to `error` instead `out` even when the `exitValue=0`

?

Comment: Check -f option for curl.
By default curl doesn't react on request errors, only on syntax errors.

Answer (score 0):

Basic behaviour of curl (when used in terminal without any option)  is to output data to standard output.

If you read curl manual about the progress meter you understand that the progress meter is normally not shown in this case https://curl.se/docs/manpage.html

For the progress meter to show,  you either have to use an option(like you did) to redirect output to a file, or directly redirect the standard output in the shell to a file  ( `curl https://... > myfile` ) or pipe.

In that case curl detect that standard output is either a pipe or a file (and not a terminal) and will automatically enable the progress meter on the standard error to not mix it with the output.

I think this is what happen in your case, the process creation creates two pipe to get the standard output and error, hence curl implementation probably switch the progress meter to the standard error because it detected that standard output is a pipe , even though you used the `-O` option

EDIT: after investigating a little i think the progress meter is always send to the standard error even if you use the -O option in terminal without any pipe or file redirection for the standard output, it's just coded that way for consistency the progress meter (when enabled) is always sent to standard error